# how to point to static folder in django

Tags: python, django, static

I am learning django and I already have a bit noobish question. I can not point to my static folder and I tried all the combinations, watched people do it in youtube tutorials etc.

My settings.py looks something like this:

```
   STATIC_ROOT = '/home/peter/brewery/static/'
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = '/home/peter/brewery/mysite/templates/'
```

where brewery/ is the folder containing mysite/ and static/, mysite/ is the folder created by

```
   django-admin.py startproject
```

where settings.py also lives...

It seems that templates folder is mapped correctly, since the page renders with proper templates, it just cannot access the css in the /static/css/ folder. I show the path in my template for css like this

```
   <link ...  href='/static/css/brewery.css' />
```

I have also tried to make href absolute path on my computer and it does not work.

I am using django 1.3 and am running the server provided by django (python manage.py runserver)

Comment: Can you try using `{{ STATIC_URL }}` in your `href`, in place of the `/static/` path? Also, if you debug using some developer tools, are you able to access the CSS file using any variations of that URL - maybe you're off by a folder or two?

Comment: You are seeing this with devserver or apache/similar web server?

Comment: How does your urls.py look like? Can you post it here?

Answer (score 4):

1 - In your settings file, define a static url and static root like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

2 - Set `DEBUG = True`

3 - Make sure your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` variable includes `django.core.context_processors.static`.

4 - Reference it in your templates like...

```
<link ...  href='{{ STATIC_URL }}css/brewery.css' />
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: +1 - please note that your `TemplateView`s (and inheritors) must call superclasses' `get_context_data()` if you override that method and not create an empty context dictionary to populate.

Answer (score 1):

In debug mode `STATIC_ROOT` is not used, but `staticfiles_urlpatterns()` provides static files from all different apps. Put your static files either into `static/` directory in one of your apps or define [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#staticfiles-dirs) in your settings and put static files for the site there.

`STATIC_ROOT` is just the location where all static files are collected from all apps and `STATICFILES_DIRS` when you call:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

And it is only used in production environment.